Run Vite HMR in WSL2, Docker and behind Nginx reverse proxy
I'm trying to get Hot Module Reload to work when developing my app locally. I have:

A Quasar app using Vue3
Docker to mimick my Cloud infrastructure to test it locally
WSL2 where Docker and thus my application runs in
A pod for the frontendcode where Vite runs in
An Nginx pod to handle incoming secure traffic
hosts file entries in both Windows and WSL Ubuntu

The app starts succesfully, I can browse to my app via my custom domainname. However the browser does not seem to connect to Vite and reloads the page every few seconds. I'm even wondering if the Vite server started but I don't see any logging that says otherwise.
What I tried to do is to create a dns routing in both Ubuntu (and thus the pods) and in Windows, so configuring the Vite server would point to the same location/pod both from my browser (Websocket to Vite) and the Vite server.
Relevant code and configuration:
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  gitrepos_frontend:
    build:
      context: ./my-frontend-project
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development  # Set the build environment variable
        BUILD_MODE: development  
    image: gitrepos_frontend
    volumes:
      - ./my-frontend-project-frontend:/app  # Mount the project directory
      - ./ssl:/etc/ssl  # Mount SSL certificates into the container
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development  # Set the runtime environment variable if needed
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    networks:
      custom_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.90.0.4

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro  # Mount the SSL directory read-only
    networks:
      custom_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.90.0.5

networks:
  custom_network:
    external:
      name: my_custom_network

My ~/.config/cni/net.d/my_custom_network.conflist:
{
   "cniVersion": "0.4.0",
   "name": "my_custom_network",
   "plugins": [
      {
         "type": "bridge",
         "bridge": "cni-podman2",
         "isGateway": true,
         "ipMasq": true,
         "hairpinMode": true,
         "ipam": {
            "type": "host-local",
            "routes": [
               {
                  "dst": "0.0.0.0/0"
               }
            ],
            "ranges": [
               [
                  {
                     "subnet": "10.90.0.0/24",
                     "gateway": "10.90.0.1"
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type": "portmap",
         "capabilities": {
            "portMappings": true
         }
      },
      {
         "type": "firewall",
         "backend": ""
      },
      {
         "type": "tuning"
      },
      {
         "type": "dnsname",
         "domainName": "dns.podman",
         "capabilities": {
            "aliases": true
         }
      }
   ]
}

nginx.conf:
events {
    worker_connections 1024;  # Adjust this value based on your server's requirements
}

http {
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Frontend and API Server Configuration
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name *.localapp.com localapp.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard.localapp.com+1.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard.localapp.com+1-key.pem;

        # Frontend location
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.90.0.4:8081;  # Use the static IP of the frontend pod
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_ssl_verify off;  # Disable SSL verification for internal services
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

frontend Dockerfile.dev:
# Development Dockerfile
FROM node:20
WORKDIR /app

# Set build-time arguments
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ARG BUILD_MODE=development

# Set environment variables from build arguments
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
ENV BUILD_MODE=$BUILD_MODE

RUN npm install -g @quasar/cli
# Copy package.json and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port the development server runs on
EXPOSE 8081

# Start the Vue development server
CMD ["quasar", "dev", "--debug"]

My quasar.config.js has:
     extendViteConf(viteConf) {
        viteConf.resolve.alias = {
          ...viteConf.resolve.alias,
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        };
        viteConf.server = {
          ...viteConf.server,
          hmr: {
            protocol: process.env.VITE_HMR_PROTOCOL || 'wss',
            host: process.env.VITE_HMR_HOSTNAME || 'localapp.com',
            port: process.env.VITE_HMR_PORT || 443,
          },
          host: '0.0.0.0', // Bind to all available IPs
          port: 8081, // Ensure this matches your Docker exposed port
        };
      },
    },

    devServer: {
      open: false,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 8081,
      allowedHosts: 'all',
      client: {
        overlay: {
          errors: true,
          warnings: false,
        },
        webSocketURL: {
          // This is critical for configuring WebSocket connections for HMR
          protocol: 'wss',
          hostname: 'localapp.com',
          port: '', // No port needed, use default SSL port 443
        },
      },
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true,
      proxy: {
        '/socket': {
          target: 'https://localapp.com',
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: true, // This is only for local development
        },
      },
      server: {
        type: 'https',
        options: {},
      },
    },

My Windows hosts file contains the IP address of my Ubuntu: 172.29.227.214    localapp.com
My Ubuntu /etc/hosts file contains the IP address of my frontend pod: 10.90.0.4       localapp.com. Starting my frontend app shows:

App dir................ /app
App URL................ http://localhost:8081/
http://10.90.0.4:8081/
Dev mode............... spa
Pkg quasar............. v2.16.4
Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.9.3
Browser target......... es2019|edge88|firefox78|chrome87|safari13.1

When I head into my frontend pod I see:

curl -I http://10.90.0.4:8081
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

This makes me think the Vite server hasn't started at all. However Quasar seems to have started correctly. Only in the browser (on Windows) I see these calls: wss://localapp.com/ which seems to timeout after a while, but I see no status in the Network tab. Who knows what I'm missing or doing wrong?
EDIT: I also tried opening up the ports:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8081 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8081 connectaddress=172.29.227.214
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WSL2 Vite Port 8081" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8081
But to no avail.

For day-to-day development, do you actually need the reverse proxy and the TLS setup?  If not, then it seems like you could just install Node (sudo apt-get install nodejs in the WSL environment, for example) and remove all of the Docker setup here.

@DavidMaze I don't need it necessary, but it is the same setup as I use in AWS cloud. I also have a Spring backend as well. I've had some problems using CORS for example and mimicking what I have running in AWS feels better for me.
